# C++ VS2013: overwriting default constructor not working

Tags: c++, class, constructor, visual-studio-2013, default-constructor

I have a weird problem in C++. Probably I am just doing something wrong, but I can't figure out, what. I am using Microsoft VS2013 if that is important.

I created a new class with two constructors:

```
class CtVolume{
public:     
    CtVolume();                                             
    CtVolume(std::string path);                             
...
```

The first one should overwrite the default constructor. This is the one that does not work as I expected. If I do something like:

```
CtVolume myVolume();
```

then I think this should call the default constructor that I defined and execute the code I implemented for it. But it doesn't. The code in my Constructor is not executed. What is even more puzzling is that I can't use the `myVolume` like an object afterwards. If I attempt to call one of the methods implemented in the class:

```
myVolume.reconstructVolume();
```

The compiler does not let me compile my code. It says:

> Error 5   error C2228: left of '.reconstructVolume' must have class/struct/union

So as it seems, this way I can't create an object.

Now, if I create the object with the keyword 'new' instead, my constructor code is being executed and everything works as expected. Example:

```
CtVolume* myVolume = new CtVolume();
myVolume->reconstructVolume();
```

This works fine.

Now another thing: if I use the *other* constructor I defined, both ways of creating the object work equally good, meaning this example:

```
CtVolume myVolume("sourcefiles/data/skullPhantom");
myVolume.reconstructVolume();
```

compiles and works as expected.

Now I tried to find out what type of `myVolume` is in the different cases, by calling `typeid(myVolume).name()`. This returns the type `class CtVolume __cdecl(void)` in the case that I described, where it "doesn't work" and `class CtVolume` in the "working" case where I used the other constructor.

Now can anybody tell me, what the `__cdecl(void)` means and what I did wrong?
What also puzzles me is that I think I did that a lot of times before and it always worked for me until now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
CtVolume myVolume();
```

is interpreted by the compiler as a function declaration. Take a look at [*most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Just do:

```
CtVolume myVolume;
```

The above code will call the default constructor appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works properly now!